# How to Stop Applications & Services from Starting on Boot?

Tags: reboot, auto-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running)

I know how to kill running applications and services via `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Running` but they keep coming back after I restart the phone.

Is there a way (or tool) to suspend their restart on boot?

Comment: @Al, thanks for providing the link to the exact duplicate. When I searched for an answer before posting I was surprised that no one asked this question before. Apparently I didn't use the right keywords. A search engine that actually finds answers based on proximity of phrasings may be a Google killer startup idea. :)

Comment: No problem. This is worth a read: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/