# Applications Start automatically , Start again if I Force Stop them or even if I Disable them

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ram, task-management

Many applications like skype , orkut, yahoo msger etc start automatically... i have already disabled and force stooped them .... I don't want to run these app and others like WiFi sleep etc to save my RAM ... I have already used Application to kill running application like Task Killer, RAM Booster etc .. but they also have limits and are unable to kill app which are installed when a new firmware is installed like Skype Yahoo msnger etc...

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How can I stop applications and services from running?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332)

Answer (score 1):

When installing you granted all of these apps an explicit permission to start when your application starts!

But for the examples you give (though I haven't ever installed Orkut myself), most of these apps offer settings internally that allows you to choose whether they start automatically.

(Recent versions of Skype have disabled launch-on-boot, have you tried updating your version?)

Comment: so it means that I should re-install the firmware after removing all apps which i don't want :/