# How to Remove Autostart for Certain Apps?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, uninstallation, task-management, auto-start

is there any way you can install an app (for instance WhatsApp) on Android 4.2.1 ICS but at the same time remove its autorun properties sothat it becomes a standalone app and ONLY uses memory, processing power and even more dear battery, only during the time that I start the application. After closing it I want it to remain unstarted!

Note: this is different than autokilling it with taskkiller and alike. I want the app to not start in the first place).

I find myself installing and de-installing certain apps to overcome this dilemma and I hope there is a better solution otherwise whats the point of Android freedom feeling, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop applications and services from running?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/16575) Please also see the [auto-start tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-start/info) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this application which allow what you ask for: [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun), though I think you need to have your phone rooted for this.
Regarding the part when you say that want the application to remain closed, that might be tricky, because that depends on the apps implementation. IF the developer is checking constantly if the service is up or down, and try to start when it is down, I advice you not to mess with it, because by trying to stop the service, then you will ended consuming more battery (you try to stop, and the application starts again, and then you stop it again, and you end in a cicle draining your battery). Starting with Gingerbread, is best to let Android manage the state of your application, as it improved greatly the memory and application management.