# Auto-start slowing me down

Tags: task-management, auto-start

My ASUS tablet runs slow. I've stopped using active desktop backgrounds, uninstalled apps that I don't use and changed the animations, but nothing seems to solve the problem. My memory is reporting at 77% full with Facebook and Twitter being two of the biggest culprits. I don't have them open all the time and only want them running when I use them. How can I prevent them from starting up? ASUS TF700T running version 4.2.1

Comment: This is a question already asked here multiple times. Please check: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575) / [questions tagged `auto-start`](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[auto-start]+answers%3A1) / our [auto-start tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-start/info) / [How can I stop applications and services from running?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/16575)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few applications that can help. Have you heard of memory booster? I would suggest download it and set it to auto clean daily (not too often), and then use the features it has (boost startup) which provides a graphical GUI to uncheck startup items- both user and system.

In regards to those two applications causing issue, I would suggest you download an application, such as Watchdog, to run in the background and ensure it is not consuming too much of your tablets resources. If you find that with both the above running and it does not help, I'd suggest format your phone and reload it, but look into running the bare minimum for a few days, then gradually add applications back on until you reach such a point where it plays up again.

Once you reach such a point that your tablet plays up again, try removing set packages and see if the issue resolves itself. If you find that it's Facebook continually, it may be feasible to go to Settings > Developer Options > Active Threads and set it to two/three (only for testing!) and see if that helps. If so, you could set Watchdog to terminate such apps on closure, effectively performing the same role the development options do.

I'm sorry, this is more of a comment however I do not have enough reputation to post them, so I rely on getting thumbs up/comments on answers.