# How can I stop yahoo starting up (trying autorun manager by mob)

Tags: auto-start, yahoo-mail

Yahoo mail is starting automatically

How can I stop it from doing so?

I have tried autoruns   MobiWIA - AndRS Studio

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun&hl=en

which shows a bunch of "intents" for yahoo mail but I don't know what to do from there.

My phone is rooted.

I can see it looks like I would have to uncheck certain intents but i'm not sure which

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/16575) As for "what to do from there": unmark the checkboxes that would be. But that also might render the app unusable, so you've got to experiment which to uncheck.

Comment: @Izzy yes I saw that, he has a section about preventing apps starting up and mentions autoruns, hence i'm using autoruns that he mentions, and yes uncheck, but what checkboxes that's the question, what intent(s) specifically to uncheck.

Comment: Hard to give general/generic advice on that. I always try to figure by their names (which are not quite readable in your screenshot) what they are about, and decide on that. If you'd e.g. uncheck #4 (PushNotificationReceiver), you'd no longer get informed you've got new mail unless you check for yourself (Cloud Messaging). The others I cannot read.

Comment: well, the aim is to stop it starting up.. i've just tried another app called startup manager. I did something and they might not be starting up now. looking under settings running apps

Comment: Of course it is. But it starts up whenever one of its intents is called. That can be `boot_completed` – but as well one of several other things, such as "network state changed", "sd card mounted", or even "battery low" – depending on what it registered listeners for. If you're rather looking for an "easy way out", you might instead try [Greenify](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify), which can "hibernate" an app when you don't explicitly run it in foreground.