# Kill all running apps automatically

Tags: settings

Is it possible to kill the running apps (SMS, browser, games ...) automatically by turn off the screen or during a certain period of time?  My device is not rooted.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running

Comment: The specific device doesn't really seem relevant for this sort of automation.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) for something like this. It doesn't kill *all* running apps (as this is [counterproductive](http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them) to Android itself for [many](http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them) reasons), but you can select apps for Greenify to hibernate each time you turn the screen off.

For me this was nice because there were several apps like ***random game*** that would run all the time, and Greenify helps this.

Also, where Greenify used to be root-only, it `now works in non-root mode, (need to be enabled in experimental features setting, Android 4.1+ required). If you have secure key-guard enabled, try "Hibernate and Lock Screen" shortcut or "Pull up" gesture on Home soft-key.` - Greenify description from Play store app page

Comment: It does now (tested today), and this is the description from their app page: `NEW: Auto-hibernation now works in non-root mode, (need to be enabled in experimental features setting, Android 4.1+ required). If you have secure key-guard enabled, try "Hibernate and Lock Screen" shortcut or "Pull up" gesture on Home soft-key.`